# Integrating contact list for windows 7 phone into app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

How do I grab the contact list of a windows 7 phone for use inside a win7 phone app?

Answer (score 3):

With the earlier version of the Windows Phone 7 SDK, it was only possible to retrieve the phone number or email address and a few more with the Choosers. Now, with the 7.1 Mango SDK, it is possible to retrieve more information from the contact, like `Address`, `DisplayName`, `EmailAddresses` etc.

I will show you how to retrieve all contacts from Windows Phone 7 using C#.

The `Contacts` Class is defined in the namespace `Microsoft.Phone.UserData` and extends from `PhoneDataSharingContext` and provides a few methods and events for interacting with a user’s contact data.

```
public MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
Contacts objContacts = new Contacts();
objContacts.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(objContacts_SearchCompleted);
objContacts.SearchAsync(string.Empty, FilterKind.None, null);
}
void objContacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
foreach (var result in e.Results)
{
lst.Add("Name : " + result.DisplayName + " ; Phone Number : " + result.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault());
}
}
```

`Contacts` can also enable the user to search for the contact with the `SearchAsync` method. The `FilterKind` determines the field that will be used for filtering like `PhoneNumber`, `DisplayName` or `EmailAddress` etc. When it is `None`, it can list all the contacts.

Note that I have used the emulator since I don't have the device with Mango currently.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
Contacts objContacts = new Contacts();
objContacts.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(objContacts_SearchCompleted);
objContacts.SearchAsync(string.Empty, FilterKind.None, null);
}

void objContacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
var ContactsData = from m in e.Results
select new MyContacts
{
DisplayName = m.DisplayName,
PhoneNumber = m.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault()
};
var MyContactsLst = from contact in ContactsData
group contact by contact.DisplayName into c
orderby c.Key
select new Group<MyContacts>(c.Key, c);
longlist1.ItemsSource = ContactsData;
}
}
public class MyContacts
{
public string DisplayName { get; set; }
public ContactPhoneNumber PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's doable in Windows Phone OS 7.1

Here's the MSDN article on [How To Access Contact List Data For Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286416.aspx)

And here's a code snippet from the article:

```
using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;

private void ButtonContacts_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Contacts cons = new Contacts();

    //Identify the method that runs after the asynchronous search completes.
    cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(Contacts_SearchCompleted);

    //Start the asynchronous search.
    cons.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, "Contacts Test #1");
}

void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
    //Do something with the results.
    MessageBox.Show(e.Results.Count().ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the contacts API is not exposed in the current version of the API. The closest you can get is using something from the Tasks namespace:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428753(v=VS.92).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428753%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

The two you can look for are the [PhoneNumberChooseTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.phonenumberchoosertask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) and [EmailAddressChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailaddresschoosertask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

alternatively, since all WP7 phones use the live contacts to sync over the air, you could always just investigate doing a web request and accessing the [Windows Live Contacts API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463982.aspx). I understand this is probably not what you're looking for, but it's probably the best option right now.

Comment: I hope future versions of the the OS will allow better integration to contact to allow apps to do more.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the user select a contact from their contact list one at a time by using PhoneNumberChooserTask (example, SDK 7.0):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769543(v=vs.92).aspx#BKMK_Phone

Also, in the Beta of the new Windows Phone SDK 7.1 release (aka Mango) one can now access all the phone's contacts:
http://www.ginktage.com/2011/05/how-to-retreive-all-contacts-from-windows-phone-7-using-c/

Note: I heard that MS will not allow apps developed in Mango to be released into the app store until fall 2011.