# How to integrate a list of contacts with mobile phone numbers into an WP7 app?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7.1

I'd like to display a list of contacts in my app. That is a simple task to do, see [this answered SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840785/integrating-contact-list-for-windows-7-phone-into-app).
Yet, I only need to display contacts which have a mobile phone number.

How to achieve this? Is there a way using LINQ?

~Chris

Answer (score 2):

Building on the [example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286416.aspx), you can do something like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Contacts cons = new Contacts();

  //Identify the method that runs after the asynchronous search completes.
  cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(Contacts_SearchCompleted);

  //Start the asynchronous search.
  cons.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, "Contacts Test #1");
}

void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
  var myMobilePhoneContacts = new List<Contact>();

  foreach (var contact in e.Results)
  {
    myMobilePhoneContacts.AddRange((from phoneNumber in contact.PhoneNumbers
                where phoneNumber.Kind == PhoneNumberKind.Mobile
            select contact).Select(cont => (Contact)cont));
  }

  // do something with the contacts in myMobilePhoneContacts
}
```

Comment: well, this works, but I hoped for cleaner solution. either way, thank you!

Comment: Yes, a better way would be if the SearchAsync method could do this for you, but it seems it only can filter based on phone number and not on type.