# Display Phone Number on Windows Phone 7.5 Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, contacts

Re-Edited My Question with code snippets...
I know this question is raised many times and the solutions already provided, yet I am not able to display Phone Numbers on windows phone emulator, but only the display name is shown.
As in windows phone 8 emulator there are no pre in-built contacts, I am using 7.5 emulator.

I did the following:
1.) Entered text, in a textbox

```
private void txtPhone_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (txtPhoneNo.Text != string.Empty) //
        {
            ContactResultsLabel.Text = "results are loading...";
            ContactResultsData.DataContext = null;

            Contacts con = new Contacts();
            con.SearchCompleted += con_SearchCompleted;                
            con.SearchAsync(txtPhoneNo.Text, FilterKind.DisplayName, "Contacts Load");
        }            
    }
```

2.) Based on the text entered, I do a searchasync for the text eneterd in textbox
3.) Fire the delegate on searchcompleted. 
Here I loop through "e.Results" to get DisplayName and PhoneNumber, and assign "e.Results" to the listbox datacontext property.

```
void con_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {                
            foreach (Contact con in e.Results)
            {
                var contactsData = from m in e.Results
                                   select new MyContacts
                                   {
                                       DisplayName = m.DisplayName,
                                       PhoneNumber = m.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault()
                                   };

                ContactResultsData.DataContext = e.Results;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            //That's okay, no results
        }

        if (ContactResultsData.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            ContactResultsLabel.Text = "results (tap name for details...)";
        }
        else
        {
            ContactResultsLabel.Text = "no results";
        }
```

4.) When I run the emulator, I get only the DisplayName, no PhoneNumber.

In XAML I have defined two textblocks inside the DataTemplate of this listbox.

```
<TextBlock Name="ContactResultsLabel" Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <ListBox Name="ContactResultsData" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="347" Margin="24,0,0,0">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                                                                                        
                                <TextBlock Name="ContactsResult" Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName,Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" Margin="18,8,0,0" />
                                <TextBlock Name="ContactsPhoneResult" Text="{Binding Path=PhoneNumber,Mode=OneWay,Source=PhoneNumbers}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" Margin="18,8,0,0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

But I am still not getting PhoneNumbers on the UI.

Also one more question, if the input scope of the textbox is string, then only the searchasync gets result for the string values entered. But if my input scope is a TelePhoneNumber say "55" for e.g. no contact results are displayed.
Can we display asyncresults for number input scope.

There is one link here for reference:
[Integrating contact list for windows 7 phone into app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840785/integrating-contact-list-for-windows-7-phone-into-app)
But my code throws error - missing reference assembly error on this line :
select new Group(c.Key, c);
It does not know what "Group" is here.

Thanks In Advance...

Comment: Any one, any help on this!!..

Comment: Illustrate your problem with some relevant code and you will be more likely to find help.

Comment: I have just used general code found online for searching contacts asynchronously...I just want some snippets or something which can just display phone numbers along with display name in emulator when searching for contacts based on the text input.

Comment: well, so show what you have, then maybe someone will try it and find the problem

Comment: you need to show up some code bro..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of not showing the phone number is in the binding of its TextBlock:

This should work there (note that only will show first phone number for each contact):

```
 <TextBlock Name="ContactsPhoneResult" Text="{Binding Path=PhoneNumbers[0]}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" Margin="18,8,0,0" />
```

Anyway, I don't understand what you intend to do in the `foreach` block of your code. It does nothing, `contactsData` is never used. Following code would do the same without being that messed up:

```
void con_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{             
    ContactResultsData.ItemsSource = e.Results;

    if (e.Results.Count > 0)
    {
        ContactResultsLabel.Text = "results (tap name for details...)";
    }
    else
    {
        ContactResultsLabel.Text = "no results";
    }
}
```

Regarding to your second question, if you want to find by phone number, you have to use `FilterKind.PhoneNumber`:

```
con.SearchAsync(txtPhoneNo.Text, FilterKind.PhoneNumber, "Contacts Load");
```

But this will not return any result unless the number coincides exactly with the one in the agenda. That is, in your case will not return any result until you type the complete number in the `TextBox`.

Comment: Ok...thanks for the answer..regarding my 2nd question for finding by phonenumber you said of using FilterKind.PhoneNumber, and then do con.SearchAsync.
But in my code based on the text entered, I filter by Display Name. So will it still work, or do I have to check the scope of the text and based on that do filtering?.
If yes, is there any code snippet of checking the input scope of a textbox and then filtering.

Comment: You can't find by phone number if you set the filter to DisplayName. You won't get any result. So yes, if you want to give the option to search using both number or name, you should check the input, and then perform the search.

Comment: But how do you check the input. Do I have to provide any other control like radio buttons, and depending on the option checked provide that filter. But then my UI would not look so great like.
Any help on the same.

Comment: There could be different approaches. For example  you could do `int.TryParse(txtPhoneNo.Text, out number)` to check in the input is a number.